# Variables will not assign from data scraped by BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am taking a tutorial on Udacity to how to learn how to scrape data from websites.
The tutorial explains the steps to extract POST parameters using BeautifulSoup and requests to send them.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.transtats.bts.gov/Data_Elements.aspx?Data=2")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

viewstate = soup.find(id='__VIEWSTATE')["value"]
eventvalidation = soup.find(id = "__EVENTVALIDATION")["value"]

r = requests.post("http://www.transtats.bts.gov/Data_Elements.aspx?Data=2",
                 data={'AirportList' : "BOS",
                       'CarrierList' : "VX" ,
                       'Submit' : "Submit"  ,
                       '__EVENTTARGET': "",
                       '__EVENTARGUMENT': "",
                       '__EVENTVALIDATION' : eventvalidation,
                       '__VIEWSTATE' : viewstate })
```

TypeErrors are thrown sometimes for assigning the `viewstate` variable and always for the `eventvalidation` variable.

This is the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-47cdc853719c> in <module>()
----> 1 viewstate = soup.find(id='__VIEWSTATE')["value"]
      2 eventvalidation = soup.find(id = "__EVENTVALIDATION")["value"]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I also get this warnign when I first request the website data and assign it to r

```
/home/dude/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py:269: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if (len(data) >= 4) and (data[:2] == b'\xfe\xff') \
/home/dude/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py:273: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  elif (len(data) >= 4) and (data[:2] == b'\xff\xfe') \
/home/dude/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py:277: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  elif data[:3] == b'\xef\xbb\xbf':
/home/dude/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py:280: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  elif data[:4] == b'\x00\x00\xfe\xff':
/home/dude/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py:283: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  elif data[:4] == b'\xff\xfe\x00\x00':
```

I know all the data are there. When I call
  `r.text` i get the expected output and I can scroll through and see the long text strings in the value for id="__EVENTVALIDATION" in the window.

Any ideas why the values cannot be assigned?

Comment: If you change to `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)` do you get the warnings? Also what version of bs4?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - I did not get the warning message when I used r.content but I am still getting the type errors when I try to assign variables.

Comment: what version of bs4 and also try `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - 4.3.2

Comment: Try changing the parser as above ^^

Comment: I did and still no worky.

Comment: what version of requests?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 2.7.0

Comment: I cannot replicate using python2 or 3, the code runs fine. If you print r.content, can you see the elements in the source?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - yes. I can see them all. I just cannot assign them. I find and assign any number of other attributes just not these ones for some reason. I will give it a try in python 3 tomorrow and then try a couple of different venvs to see what happens. Thanks for looking into to it though,

Comment: Yes indeed - this is only happening with the anaconda version of Python.